# Problem with S parameter calculation

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, transmission-line, microwave

A load of 50Ω is connected in shunt in a 2-wire transmission line of Z0
= Ω 50 as
shown in the figure. The 2-port scattering parameter matrix (S-matrix) of the
shunt element is:
[image]

**Method 1**

The line is terminated with 50 ohms at the ends, so matched on both the sides thus
$$\ S_{11} = 0, S_{22} = 0 $$and $$S_{12} = S_{21} = 1 $$

Option(B) is correct.

Is this the correct Method? If Not PLZ provide the solution.

Comment: Somewhere I found Option C Is correct so I am confused Now.

Comment: The line is not matched on either side. Looking from the left, you see the 50-ohm load *and* the transmission line following it further to the right. Please try to apply this hint and [edit] your post if you need further help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that when you calculate the \$S_{x1}\$ parameters you connect a matched load to port 2, and when you calculate the \$S_{x2}\$ parameters you connect a matched load on port 1. Matched means having the same value as \$Z_0\$.

Option B is not correct. I can immediately tell that because option B implies 0 reflected waved, which is obviously wrong.

To choose which of options A, C, and D is correct, you can just calculate either the reflection parameter, since the three choices all have different reflection values.